# Pandas read format %D:%H:%M:%S with python

Tags: python, pandas, time, timestamp, timedelta

Currently I am reading in a data frame with the timestamp from film 00(days):00(hours clocks over at 24 to day):00(min):00(sec)

`pandas` reads time formats HH:MM:SS and YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS fine.
Though is there a way of having pandas read the duration of time such as the DD:HH:MM:SS.

Alternatively using timedelta how would I go about getting the DD into HH in the data frame so that pandas can make it "1 day HH:MM:SS" for example

Data sample

```
00:00:00:00
00:07:33:57 
02:07:02:13 
00:00:13:11 
00:00:10:11 
00:00:00:00 
00:06:20:06 
01:12:13:25
```

Expected output for last sample

```
36:13:25
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you ad some data sample and expected ouput? E. g. 2-3 values.

Comment: 00:00:00:00
00:07:33:57
02:07:02:13
00:00:13:11
00:00:10:11
00:00:00:00
00:06:20:06


01:12:13:25

for the last one I would need to get 36:13:25

Comment: I think in [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71405377/edit) and also add expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want timedelta objects, a simple way is to replace the first colon with `days` :

```
df['timedelta'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['col'].str.replace(':', 'days ', n=1))
```

output:

```
           col       timedelta
0  00:00:00:00 0 days 00:00:00
1  00:07:33:57 0 days 07:33:57
2  02:07:02:13 2 days 07:02:13
3  00:00:13:11 0 days 00:13:11
4  00:00:10:11 0 days 00:10:11
5  00:00:00:00 0 days 00:00:00
6  00:06:20:06 0 days 06:20:06
7  01:12:13:25 1 days 12:13:25
```

```
>>> df.dtypes
col                   object
timedelta    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

From there it's also relatively easy to combine the days and hours as string:

```
c = df['timedelta'].dt.components
df['str_format'] = ((c['hours']+c['days']*24).astype(str)
                    +df['col'].str.split('(?=:)', n=2).str[-1]).str.zfill(8)
```

output:

```
           col       timedelta str_format
0  00:00:00:00 0 days 00:00:00   00:00:00
1  00:07:33:57 0 days 07:33:57   07:33:57
2  02:07:02:13 2 days 07:02:13   55:02:13
3  00:00:13:11 0 days 00:13:11   00:13:11
4  00:00:10:11 0 days 00:10:11   00:10:11
5  00:00:00:00 0 days 00:00:00   00:00:00
6  00:06:20:06 0 days 06:20:06   06:20:06
7  01:12:13:25 1 days 12:13:25   36:13:25
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert days separately, add to times and last call custom function:

```
def f(x):
    ts = x.total_seconds()
    hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return ('{}:{:02d}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds)) 


d = pd.to_timedelta(df['col'].str[:2].astype(int), unit='d')
td = pd.to_timedelta(df['col'].str[3:])
df['col'] =  d.add(td).apply(f)
print (df)
        col
0   0:00:00
1   7:33:57
2  55:02:13
3   0:13:11
4   0:10:11
5   0:00:00
6   6:20:06
7  36:13:25
```

Comment: this looks like it could work, could you clarify what it does? IIUC convert everything to seconds and then back to hours, min, sec and put back into the df?

Comment: @Deerled - answer was edeted.